# How do I set up a GCM BroadcastReceiver when my app has multiple activities?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an application that is to receive push notifications using Google Cloud Messaging. The problem is that I'm running registerReceiver() in an "SplashActivity" that I use for doing some initial work, fetching and registering at the GCM server. The problem is that when the activity is done doing this, it opens the MainActivity using an Intent, and I get the error message:

```
Activity <package>.SplashActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
<package>.GCMMessageReceiver@40ed1c38 that was originally 
registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

What to do here? I don't want to unregister the IntentReceiver when leaving the activity, as I want the app to keep receiving push notifications (even when closed). What's the recommended way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the app to keep receiving push notifications (even when closed)

Then why are you using `registerReceiver()`? Put the `<reciever>` in the manifest, like [the GCM sample demonstrates](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#manifest).

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke registerReceiver() from an activity then its tied to the Activity's context.
Instead, invoke getApplicationContext().registerReceiver().

And... make sure that your BroadcastReciever object is not directly tied to SplashAcitivty. I.e., dont use an inner (non-static) class as BroadcastReciever object.
I usually keep such stuff away from the activites and do it in the Application singleton instead.

Comment: Thank you, saved my day! When I registered, I used "this" instead of "getApplicationContext()".